# Using list comprehension to create a list of lists in a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, list-comprehension

I am experimenting with recursive functions. My goal is to produce:

> A function `combo` that generates all non-increasing series that add up to n

Some sample inputs/outputs:

```
>>> print (combo(3))
[[3], [2, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
>>> print (combo(4))
[[4], [3, 1], [2, 2], [2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
>>> print (combo(5))
[[5], [4, 1], [3, 2], [3, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1], [2, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

After a lot of trial and error, I came up with the following function which does exactly what I want:

```
def combo(n, limit=None):
    if not limit:
        limit = n
    # return [ LIST COMPREHENSION HERE ]
    res = []
    for i in range(limit, 0, -1):
        if i == n:
            res.append([i])
        else:
            res.extend([i] + x for x in combo(n - i, min(n - i, i)))
    return res
```

My question: **Is there a way (pythonic or not) to return this same result using a single list comprehension, without appending to and extending `res`**?

Here are two things I've tried, along with their mangled results:

```
return [[i] if i == n else [[i] + x for x in combo(n - i, min(n - i, i))] for i in range(limit, 0, -1)]
# lists get deeper: [[4], [[3, 1]], [[2, 2], [2, [1, 1]]], [[1, [1, [1, 1]]]]]

return [[i if i == n else ([i] + x for x in combo(n - i, min(n - i, i))) for i in range(limit, 0, -1)]]
# parentheses interpreted as generator: [[4, <generator object combo.<locals>.<listcomp>.<genexpr> at 0x01D84E40>, etc.]]
```

I realize that the answer may be quite ugly, but I've spent enough time trying that I just want to know if it is *possible*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert *extending* to *appending* and it becomes easier to grok how to convert this:

```
res = []
for i in range(limit, 0, -1):
    if i == n:
        res.append([i])
    else:
        # this is the generator expression pulled out of the res.extend() call
        for x in combo(n - i, min(n - i, i)):
            res.append([i] + x)
```

You can now move the `i == n` case into the other branch (using a helper `items` variable here for readability):

```
res = []
for i in range(limit, 0, -1):
    items = [[]] if i == n else combo(n - i, min(n - i, i))
    for x in items:
        res.append([i] + x)
```

If `i == n`, this causes the loop iterate once and produce an empty list, so you effectively get `res.append([i])`.

This can then trivially be converted to a list comprehension (inlining `items` into the `for` loop):

```
return [
    [i] + x
    for i in range(limit, 0, -1)
    for x in ([[]] if i == n else combo(n - i, min(n - i, i)))]
```

Wether or not you *should* is another matter; this is hardly easier to read.

Comment: Works with your latest edit (parentheses). Many thanks for the thoughtful response!

Comment: @brianpck: yeah, I am surprised at that, since a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) is the topmost component of the `expression` rule in the Python grammar, which is part of the [`expression_list` rule](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists) that [`for` accepts](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement). I'll look further as to why this is an issue.

Comment: Without knowing too much about syntax rules, it appears that the `if` is being assumed to be a part of the condition list comprehension syntax, e.g. `[i for i in x if i == 1]`

Comment: @brianpck: yup, that's the conclusion I was coming to too :-D My mistake was going to the `for` loop grammar, not the [comprehension grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-comprehension).